# Status Message: Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value. (Code:InvalidParameterValue)

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I get this error while creating a SQL database via ARM templates:

> Status Message: Invalid value given for parameter Login. Specify a valid parameter value. (Code:InvalidParameterValue)

[image]

Comment: Post your ARM template.

Comment: Yes could you please add more details so we can try to reproduce ? the arm template, the command you're executing etc.